# How to refresh the admin/app view after some time in django

Tags: python, django, view, django-views, admin

My app has two users, frontend and backend.
The frontend user will insert the data and the backend user will check the record of the app in the admin panel.

I want to refresh the app view of the admin panel every 10 or so seconds.

[image: View of the app]

On the frontend, I can use this script to refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    location = ''
  },60000)
</script>
```

But how do I refresh the backend?
I have searched and there are lots of stuff using ajax jquery, and others but I am sorry I am not familiar with any of them.

Just want a simple solution. Is it even possible?

Comment: a simple solution will be to create a view to display that data on the front-end  and using permission to limit which user can see that data ))

Comment: But the admin or Backend user will also update, see the data.

Comment: it is better not to allow backend user to have the url of the admin or have access to it,only you(the admin) should have access to it.that is why i say it is better to have a view and make some logic(using permissions or ...) there to see ,update,validate,... data and with that you can see who did what but in the admin i do not think you can do that.

Comment: Ok. Let me see if i can make it work...

Answer (score 1):

override the admin changelist template and add that same code you have there.
make a template called `[your model]_changelist.html`. put it in [your app]/templates/admin/[your app]

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script>
       [your script]
    <script>
{% endblock %}
```

Then in admin.py

```
class [your model]Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     change_list_template = "admin/[your app]/[your model]_changelist.html"
```